# How to spit out a JavaScript variable (type array) from Custom Control

Tags: asp.net

I want to spit out a JS variable array like so from my custom control:

var myArray = [5410, 8362, 6638, 6758, 7795]

caveat is that I want it to also be unique to this control as this control will spit out more JavaScript that will utilize myArray.  So I envision something like:

var [control'sID]myArray = [5410, 8362, 6638, 6758, 7795]

and then somehow the rest of the JavaScript that is spit out can reference this somehow where needed in the JS code.  I've got certain methods in the other JavaScript that is being spit out that is using myArray.

Comment: With "the rest of the JavaScript" do you mean javascript generated outside of the control?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ClientID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx)
C# Example:

```
Response.Write("var " + this.ClientID + "myArray = [5410, 8362, 6638, 6758, 7795];");
```

VB Example:

```
Response.Write("var " & Me.ClientID & "myArray = [5410, 8362, 6638, 6758, 7795];")
```

Comment: So you wouldn't use something like RegisterExpandoAttribute ?  Just curious

Comment: And what is ClientID vs. UniqueID?

Comment: RegisterExpandoAttribute sets an attribute on an element after the page is loaded. It doesn't "spit" out javascript the way you want.

Comment: UniqueID: my bad... it should be ClientID... otherwise you'll get errors.

Comment: ClientID vs. UniqueID: UniqueID uses ":" while ClientID uses "_". You do not want ":" in your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to generate a javascript array from your custom control, and you want to access it from your main library,

You can use your control's ClientID property to make your arrays unique.

And you can define a global array to keep the array's names to access them from your rest of the client scripts.

**EDIT :**

I just look at the [RegisterExpandoAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153122.aspx) method, it's an interesting method, I have never heard that before. [In this example](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/11/26/Adding_ClientSide_Custom_Properties_To_Controls.aspx) it looks like it you can add custom attributes to your control.

So you can use it in your custom control like that :

Just add a custom attribute that has your array items with comma separated. and when accessing the custom attribute, simply split them by comma. I think this will work for your question.

**At your custom control :**

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterExpandoAttribute(this.ClientID
   , "myArray", "1,2,3,4");
```

**At client side, get your array like that :**

```
var myArray = 
   document.getElementById('<%= this.ClientID %>').getAttribute("myArray")).split(',');
```

Comment: that's what I figured.  I just wanted to see if you guys came up with another solution because I've been told I could use the RegisterExpandoAttribute but I don't see the value in it in my case.